# Github API - Users two factor authentication

Tags: github, github-api, two-factor-authentication

I want to know if all users from my organization has the two factor authentication enabled. Is it possible to do via API? I searched through the v3 and v4 APIs but I can't find anything about it.

I know that I can see this information via browser but I want to know if its possible via API

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I would expect anything and everything related to security features to be hidden from API consumers.  If you *were* able to figure out if I had 2-factor enabled, that would just allow you exclude me from a targeted attack and focus on those that did not have 2-factor enabled.  If GitHub exposed this, I'd ask, "why?".

Comment: Well, it looks like you can get it with v3 at least if the user allows it in their scopes: [`two_factor_authentication`](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#response-with-public-and-private-profile-information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information using the `/members` endpoint: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#members-list.

GitHub has probably thought about your particular use case because you can query for members that specifically have 2FA disabled:

[image]